# Validating checkbox fails (Form > jQuery validation > PHP)

Tags: jquery, validation

I have been seriously trying to solve this issue for hours now, have read plenty of responses here but it just won't work.

I mark a post as important in my database by setting a single column to either 0 (not important) or 1 (important). The state should be determined by checking (or not checking) a text form within the form on my site. While this works all fine when I send the form straight to the php processing script, it doesn't work when validating the form with jQuery. For some reason in this case it ALWAYS marks the post as important, whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Check out the code:

FORM

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Form Title</legend>

  <label>Title *</label>
  <input type="text" name="headline" placeholder="...">
  <label>Contentn *</label>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="important" id="important" value="checked">
    Important
  </label><br>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit-post" value="Send">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Validation Part

```
$(document).ready ( function() {
$('.submit-post').click(function() {          

    // VALIDATION PART
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var headline = form.find('input[name=headline]');
    var content = form.find('textarea[name=content]'); 

    if( $('input[type=checkbox]:checked') ) {
        var important = 1;
    } else {
        var important = 0;
    }

    var passed = true;

    if (headline.val()=='') {
        headline.addClass('highlight');
        passed = false;
    } else {
        headline.removeClass('highlight');
    }

    if (content.val()=='') {
        content.addClass('highlight');
        form.find('.errorMessage').fadeIn();
        passed = false;
    } else {
        content.removeClass('highlight');
    }

    if (!passed) {
        return false;
    }

    //organize the data properly
    var data = 'headline=' + headline.val() + '&content=' + content.val() + '&important=' + important.val();

    //disabled all the text fields
    form.find('.text').attr('disabled','true');

    //show the loading sign
    $('.loading').show();

    //start the ajax
    var request = $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        // data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            if (html == "true") {

                form.find('.sendMessage').attr('disabled','true');
                form.find('.successMessage').fadeIn();

            } else {
                alert("There was an error with your entry. Please try again later while we fix it! :)");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            // Fail
            alert("Form Error: " + error);
        }
    });

    //cancel the submit button default behaviours
    return false;

});
```

});

PHP

```
    <?php 

    include 'functions.php';

    // Check if form is submitted
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && !empty($_POST['headline']) &&          !empty($_POST['content']) ) {

// Get job details
$title = ($_POST['headline']);
$content = ($_POST['content']);
$compensation = ($_POST['compensation']);
$category = ($_POST['category']);

// Check whether job was marked as 'important'
if ( isset($_POST['important']) ) {
    $important = 1 ;
} else {
    $important = 0;
}

// Get author details
$author_email = $_SESSION['email'];
$author_id = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? ");
$author_id->bindParam(1, $author_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$author_id->execute();

$get_author_id = $author_id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$get_author_id = $get_author_id['id'];

// Here I add the information to the database

echo json_encode(true);
    } else {
echo "Error: Error submitting data to database";
    exit();
    }

    ?>
```

Anyone an idea what is going on? I tried in all possible ways but I can't get it working! I would really appreciate your help.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

you should change `$important = 1;` to :

```
if ( isset($_POST['important']) ) {
    $important = $_POST['important'];
} else {
    $important = 0;
}
```

also you have issue here:

```
var data = '.....&important=' + important.val();
```

it must be like :

```
var data = '.....&important=' + important;
```

remove `.val()` from `important.val()`

Comment: Thanks mgraph. Unfortunately, now it doesn't even submit anymore. The weird thing is that I don't get an error message. When hitting the submit button it simply doesn't do anything.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. The form would not submit at all then. The PHP script works fine though. The problem must be within the validation script. Can you think of anything else that could cause this problem?

Comment: Thanks again mgraph! So now I get this error "There was an error with your entry. Please try again later while we fix it! :)", which basically means that the php script doesn't return true I guess. However, when I send the form straight to the script it works fine. So there must be some issue with getting and validating the checkbox, which then affects the whole form processing.

Comment: @domdev try to do an `alert(html)` to see what it returns, before `if (html == "true") {`

Comment: It says "Error: Error submitting data to database". I also did an alert(important) and it returns 1 even if the checkbox is not checked. Could this cause the problems?

Comment: Ok, now it correctly determines the state of the checkbox. However, I still get the error above! 

`if ( $('#important').attr('checked') ) {
        var important = 1;
        } else {
        var important = 0;
        }`